# Camel Query OrderBy not working for Decimal Number

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, number, orderby

I have column name `OrderBy` of Type Number:

[image]

I am using below CAML Query:

```
"<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='OrderBy'  Ascending='TRUE' /> 
</OrderBy></Query></View>";
```

In `OrderBy` Column I have following values:

- 2
- 2.1
- 2.5
- 2.9
- 2.10

So Expected result should be in following order:

- 2
- 2.5
- 2.9
- 2.10

But Actual result is

- 2
- 2.10
- 2.1
- 2.5
- 2.9

So my CAML query is not working as expected, please help.

Comment: I guess the actual result is correct and it is in Ascending order only.

Answer (score 1):

Two Options!

1. the function works properly but uses some strange string sorting on decimal values
2. the function is not running at all, because the name in your FieldRef is propable wrong. I have something in mind that 'space' in Fieldnames ist masked as '_x0020_'. So maybe it works better with

   FieldRef Name='Order_x0020_By'

[ inofficial option 3: I'm wrong with everything I wrote ;-) ]